# A sequence in a metric space that converge to a point of that metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, metric-spaces

I found a next statement to prove, but I think there's something wrong with it or I just can't prove it:

If $(x_n)$ is a sequence in a metric space $(X,d)$ which converges to $l \in X$ then $ \{x_n : n \in \mathbb{N} \}$ is either empty or equal to $\{l\}$

Isn't a $\{1/n\}$ sequence contradicts that statement on $\mathbb{R}$?
I'm not sure if this statement is missing some other condition...

**Edit**

Actually think there is a missing "discrete" word before metric space in the statement or something like that. With a discrete metric it make sense.

The case of empty set I think is true by vacuous argument:

For any $\epsilon > 0$ the existe an $N$, s.t. for all $n \geq N$ we have $d(x_n, l) < \epsilon$. But as the sequence is empty there's no $x_n$ to choose and the argument is vacuously true. Not sure about this but it similar to the "empty set is open" proves.

Thanks

Comment: how can $\{x_n\mid n\in\mathbb N\}$ being empty ?

Comment: It seems quite strange. Anyway, I would consider "exotic" distances, such as the discrete metric.

Comment: The statement is clearly false as it stands. One might ask for an **example** of a metric space with that property, though the wording would still be rather weird: the only way that $\{x_n:n\in\Bbb N\}$ could be empty is if there is no sequence converging to $\ell$, but the constant sequence at $\ell$ always converges to $\ell$, so in fact that set is never empty.

Comment: I think "discrete" word missed probably as I stated in the edit. The empty part is actually the "empty sequence" or that "the set of elements of the sequence is empty" (which I think means the same after all). In both cases as far I understand it makes sense as it's a set of elements of $X$ after all.